# MvvmCross android binding to fragment

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

is there any way to bind in layout directly to custom fragment?
ie:

```
<fragment       android:id="@+id/AwesomeFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                local:MvxBind="CustomTarget PropertyInVM;" class="My.Awesome.Fragment" />
```

CustomTarget is CustomTargetBinding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So how you can do this:

1. create custom control with properties you need
2. create target bindings
3. place custom control into layout instead of your fragment
4. bind from layout